# Inconsistent SVG rendering between desktop and mobile - is Arial a web-safe font in SVG?

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, svg, text

I have an SVG which is predominantly text.

It is rendering identically (and correctly) in Firefox 53 and Chrome 58 on Windows 7.

It is rendering identically (but incorrectly) in Firefox Mobile 53 and Chrome Mobile 58 on Android 6.

The incorrect rendering is related to spacing - two non-text elements are incorrectly positioned and one non-text element is wider than it ought to be.

My guess is that the font is rendering differently - but would **Arial** on Android 6 render differently from **Arial** on Windows 7?

Here is my SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewbox="0 0 805 120">

<defs>

<filter id="shadow" x="0" y="0">
<feOffset result="offOut" dx="2" dy="2" />
<feColorMatrix result="matrixOut" values="0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
<feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2" />
<feBlend in="SourceGraphic" mode="normal" />
</filter>

<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[

svg {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 84px;
font-weight: 900;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

text, rect, path {
fill: rgb(0, 75, 165);
stroke: rgb(30, 40, 90);
stroke-width: 1;
}

rect + text {
fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

a:nth-of-type(2) rect {
stroke: none;
fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

path {
transform: translate(414px, 12px);
}


]]></style>
</defs>

<a xlink:href="http://handsoffhri.org/"><text x="0" y="70" filter="url(#shadow)">#Hands</text><rect x="396" y="0" width="200" height="80" /><text x="406" y="70">Off</text><text x="603" y="70" filter="url(#shadow)">HRI</text></a>

<a xlink:href="http://handsoffnhs.org/">
<rect x="426" y="20" width="30" height="40" />
<path d="M 17.923077,46.076923 C 14.343392,42.497239 14.27418,40.818155 17.53034,36.54911 19.670795,33.742828 19.964561,32.558959 19.43687,28.865832 19.093774,26.464624 18.091959,22.925 17.210613,21 15.473393,17.205632 14.946739,8.8090066 16.395225,8 c 0.492374,-0.275 1.522812,1.75 2.289861,4.5 0.76705,2.75 1.785893,5.9 2.264097,7 0.478204,1.1 1.121144,2.7875 1.428755,3.75 0.388325,1.215052 1.601353,1.75 3.968232,1.75 1.874918,0 3.94672,0.647984 4.604006,1.439966 0.657286,0.791981 2.129739,1.579481 3.272118,1.75 3.300549,0.492661 6.095959,4.949339 4.942528,7.879795 C 38.638723,37.406393 37.617787,40.525 36.896075,43 c -1.470078,5.04141 -2.354638,5.96259 -5.746769,5.984687 -2.184572,0.01423 -2.312807,-0.285031 -1.814586,-4.234687 0.29486,-2.3375 0.828492,-5.625597 1.18585,-7.306882 0.910327,-4.282879 -1.674633,-6.518656 -4.539328,-3.926143 -2.445773,2.213395 -2.522575,5.352525 -0.231242,9.451617 1.687087,3.018122 1.680216,3.182812 -0.19113,4.581039 -2.817812,2.105407 -4.353952,1.809133 -7.635793,-1.472708 z M 5.9073963,33.25 2.6076082,29.5 5.0157824,29.152671 C 7.7278899,28.761505 11,32.019342 11,35.110784 11,37.937782 9.573836,37.416676 5.9073963,33.25 Z M 41.007272,27 c 0.549073,-1.375 1.491079,-3.7375 2.093346,-5.25 0.602268,-1.5125 1.726011,-2.75 2.497207,-2.75 2.311553,0 1.576924,2.264983 -2.108223,6.5 -2.678238,3.077864 -3.250499,3.423665 -2.48233,1.5 z m -8.000683,-3.75 c 0.0036,-0.9625 0.900659,-3.1 1.993411,-4.75 1.092752,-1.65 1.989787,-4.4074 1.993411,-6.127555 0.0073,-3.4695992 2.322706,-6.2880071 3.543292,-4.3130587 0.626634,1.0139159 -1.08136,7.8982867 -3.644702,14.6906137 -1.001533,2.653854 -3.894924,3.026194 -3.885412,0.5 z m -6.936221,-3.118517 c -0.55,-1.027684 -0.689818,-2.1787 -0.310706,-2.557811 0.379112,-0.379112 0.559103,-3.58828 0.39998,-7.131483 C 25.922072,5.152178 26.148965,4 27.42827,4 c 1.304453,0 1.537588,1.4643706 1.432844,9 -0.123753,8.903267 -0.849702,10.758358 -2.790746,7.131483 z" id="path3690" />
</a>

</svg>
```

What do I need to explicitly declare in my XML, in order that the SVG renders identically between desktop and mobile? Thanks.

Comment: [Arial is a Microsoft font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial). AFAIK, Android devices do not have Arial.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. So we think maybe Android is displaying a different font, not Arial? If that's the issue - ie. Arial is _not_ web-safe - then I guess I'm looking for a sans-serif font which is native to Windows, Mac OS, Linux, iOS and Android (?)

Comment: Is the better approach to convert the text to outlines and then use `<path>` instead of `<text>`? If at all possible I would like to achieve cross-platform-compatibility, while _maintaining accessibility_.

Comment: Font renderering is most of the time different on the different OS, even the same font or library to render the font is used. This can result in slightly different weights of the font but it especially affects the spacing/kerning of the fonts.

Comment: Arial _is_ as web-safe as it can be. I would suggest going for a “native font stack” such as `font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;` ([see more info](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/reboot/#native-font-stack)), that way you'll always get the best sans-serif font available. If you really need Arial, you should convert the SVG text to outlines.

Comment: @edmundo this is terrible advice, yeas Arial is as web safe as it can be, meaning NOT AT ALL, and your proposed stack is no better, it's just tweaked to your particular system. Web ≠ Windows + OSX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to convert text to path interpretation (it's actual not only for SVG, but for any design element; a basic recommendation from Corel/A.Illustrator).

Additional way is to import required fonts (by using Google Fonts or internal files in woff/woff2/eot/ttf/svg group). Please, note, that the current solution is working only for `<object>` or inline-svg (not workable for `<img>`):

```
<defs>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: Arial;
            src: url('font_path/arial-like-font.woff');
        }
    </style>
</defs>
```

Comment: I have considered converting to path. But if I convert text to path, I am guessing the text will not copy-paste and (arguably, more importantly) it will not be machine-readable. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah... after convertation it won't be selectable or machine-readable. In that case just use similar font by using `@font-face` for an identical representation under different devices/OS/browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Android, but on most Linux distros isn't Arial available out of the box, it's really far better just to use the same font family and if you are dependent on the same way of rendering, just convert the text to path as @FieryCat suggested (and insert the real text as an alt test)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, custom fonts are an issue with SVGs. If the font is not included in your css, then it will not transfer to mobile. even then, mobile may change it.

Solution: Convert your fonts to Outlines before exporting.

Use Adobe Illustrator to create your SVGs. Before exporting / saving, use the Type -> Create Outlines to convert your fonts to paths. That will help in retaining your SVGs.